# how to continue timer in app when come back from onRestart state

Tags: android, timer, handler, runnable, activity-lifecycle

i've created a small app of memory game. in that app i have created a timer that show the time that take the user to finish the game. my problem is that the timer freeze after i go to another page (like home screen) and back to the game- the time remain at the same time it was stopped.....(i khnow it related somehow to onRestarte() method but dont know what to do..) i want that the timer will continue at the same time it has been stopped. (like if the user have an incall in the middle of the game and then want to continue).

```
    package com.example.kineret.memorygame;



    public class Game4x4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener{

    TextView timerTextView;
    long startTime = 0;
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game4x4);
        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView4x4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(newGame) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
            newGame = false;
        }

        // rest of my code...

}
```

Comment: Please can you explain little bit more ? what you want ? when user go another page timer is stopped. but you want that timer should stop or not and running in background ?

Comment: no, i dont want that the timer will continue in the background when the user go to another page. i want that the time stop when the app is in the background, and will continue from the same spot it was before - when the user come back to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have edited your code. plz try this

```
public class Game4x4Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener{

    // make a new variable
    static long elapsedTime = 0;
    TextView timerTextView;
    long startTime = 0;
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // change here
            long millis = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + elapsedTime;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;

            timerTextView.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game4x4);
        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView4x4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // change here
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // change here
        if(!newGame) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: just want to understand, why didn't you use in the "onRestart()" method instesd of the "onResume()"?

Comment: ok, it's not worked in perfection... now when i start a new game, it still count the time with the elapsed time..

Comment: i make `elapsedTime` a static variable, so my dear in onCreate() methode again put `elapsedTime = 0;` it will solve your problem. Thanks

Comment: onResume() called when onStop() called. so in some cases, onStop() does not called, That's why i put this code in onResume(). but if you want you can put these line of code in onRestart();

Answer (score 0):

If the user gets a phone call your app will call `onPause` then if they finish their phone call and play your game your activity will get `onResume` called.

in `onPause` save the system time, in `onResume` get the latest system time. Take these away from each other (in `onResume`) and you will have the time that the user was not in your app, you can then add this to your timer before you restart it.

You may also have to persist this time with `onSaveInstanceState` at other points.

Comment: thanku very much. i know the logic i dont know how to write it in android sintax..